# AngularJS ng-view, ng-click and routerProvider not working together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been scratching my head for some time over this puzzle. I've been trying to load an external file into an ng-view (no problems here). And in that partial file I have text that get swapped for an input field when you click "Edit title", but this only works when all code is included in the same file.

If you take a look at this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cgUGOKVzWKNWugqrFCbJ you'll see what I mean.

I would appreciate if you could point me in a direction that could solve this issue for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "#" in the hrefs are probably making angular render the html and the controller again.

Change them as below and it should work:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit title</a>
```

Comment: or just set it to empty `href=""`

Comment: @Codezilla is correct, although I prefer to set it as empty as sza has demonstrated

Comment: That's the prize you pay for copying others code. But why did it work when the code wasn't handled by the ng-view?

Comment: @ola The address changes are taken into consideration only when you are using routing. So if you don't use ng-view, clicking on links with hash does not make angular reload the template and the controller.